# Good IDE to get started with prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to start learning Prolog for my job.

I haven't used Prolog before and my company needs to build a program that will use Prolog.

So the program will be used commercially.

So some questions:

1) Does Prolog use a compiler to compile the programs. Like gcc does for c?

2) Is there commercial standard of Prolog? I have only heard of SWI Prolog.

3) I have been using GNU Emacs with Linux for many years. I am thinking of using the Prolog.el package? Any comments on that?

Many thanks for any answers,

Comment: I'm very interested. What kind of program are your building? Will you be building everything from scratch or does it need to interface to existing code?

Comment: Hello, good question. I will be building everything from scratch and just to add some extra fun to it. I will have to interface with some C shared library. So I will have to register some call backs so that my prolog application can receive an event from the c library. So I will need to research how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: SWI-Prolog has several interfaces to C code; among them is a SICStus compatibility layer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The most elaborate Prolog IDE I'm familiar with is the Eclipse-based IDE for Amzi! Prolog.  This is a commercial product, but the IDE can be downloaded and used for free in the Student Edition.  It might be ideal for a beginning Prolog programmer.  Disclaimer:  I may be biased because I supply a lot of free advice at Amzi!'s support forum.  I think there's an open source Eclipse plugin that supports some of the open source Prolog implementations as well.  **Update** (May, 2016) Amzi! Prolog v. 10 has now [become open source](http://www.amzi.com/) using an MIT-like license.
2. Although SWI-Prolog is open source (GPL), it is possible to develop commercial applications with it, as with several other open source Prolog implementations like GNU Prolog and YAP.  Besides Amzi! Prolog there are several other commercial products.  Visual Prolog is different enough from the ISO standard for Prolog that most Prolog programmers do not consider it "real prolog".  SICStus Prolog is an ISO compliant commercial Prolog implementation.  There are some others that are Prolog-like but with substantial extensions, such as ECLiPSe (not to be confused with the IDE) and Mercury.  A number of commercial implementations of Prolog have become obsolete over the years, as when IF Prolog was superseded by MINERVA.  Here's  [a list of implementations](http://www.prolog.info/compilers.html) from 2006.
3. I know many programmers who speak highly of the Prolog mode for GNU EMACS.  However I'd think a beginner would benefit from an integrated debugger/editor such as Amzi! Prolog offers.  SWI-Prolog has a graphical IDE under construction based on XPCE, which is the graphical interface library SWI-Prolog has chosen for cross-platform development.  Almost all programmer editors will supply syntax highlighting for Prolog, with the right definitions file installed.

Comment: @AndersonGreen:  It looks like you posted a link from a Google search results page, which is perhaps not what you meant to do.

Comment: There is another Prolog IDE called [Prolog Studio](http://interprolog.com/interprolog-studio/).

Answer (score 4):

[SICStus Prolog](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/) has an [IDE based on Eclipse](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/). The SICStus IDE has many advanced features not found in competing products, free or commercial. Among other things it detects syntax errors and other common mistakes as you type, which can be especially valuable for a beginner.

SICStus also has an Emacs mode but it does not offer all of the functionality of the Eclipse-based IDE.

You can download an evaluation of SICStus Prolog from the [home page](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/).

I am biased, I am one of the SICStus Prolog developers and the developer of the SICStus Prolog IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can generally compile your prolog project. However, depending on the prolog environment you are using, it might be an intermediate code and not directly executable code.
SWI Prolog and Sicstus prolog both allow to generate an executable of this form (embedding the interpreter along with you compiled intermediate code).
Other prologs like Arity Prolog/32 compiles directly to an x86 executable. There is a page on Wikipedia that [compares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations) various prolog systems.

There is an ISO standard for prolog. However almost every prolog system will be mostly compatible with each other, requiring minor changes to port the code from one prolog system to another.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what gusbro already said: SWI-Prolog is, I think, the best Prolog for learning. It may not be the fastest implementation, but is has quite a few bells & whistles such as command line editing and a built-in Emacs-like editor, it's free software and it's easy to install on both Windows and Linux (and Mac OS X, too, I reckon). It's implemented as a bytecode compiler for a virtual machine, like most Prologs; even the ones that produce native code often use a virtual machine at some point.

The basics of Prolog are much the same among implementations; non-standard extensions such as extra libraries, OS interfaces, constraint programming etc. tend to be a little different.

Various Prolog-Java and Prolog-C# interfaces interfaces exist. SWI has extensions that allow it to function as a web server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the swi-prolog built in ide for commercial development.

Depending on your os, you might need to start with swipl-win.exe or xpce
to get the graphic environment

Answer (score 2):

I am using an eclipse IDE plug-in called [PDT](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs/v2.1/download). The installation is fairly easy and I think it is a nice environment. After installation, you can follow the instructions at the "[getting started page](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs/v2.1/getting_started)" to finish your installation and get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

if you are used to work in an emacs environment you should try using the Ciao distribution. It has many interesting and powerful features, libraries, and is also GNU LGPL license. Highly documented and supported.
Go to http://ciaohome.org/